# How to have php-gd extension in Laravel Vapor?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

I am trying to include php-gd extension in laravel vapor as assumingly in does not have out of the box. I need the extension for this package https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel, which I use for csv exports.

This is what vapor returns on deployment when composer tries to install the package.

[image]

From what this post hints:

https://blog.laravel.com/vapor-adding-imagick-as-a-separate-lambda-layer

I understand that I need to use or build my own lambda layer with the php GD extension present so I can include it as an extra vapor layer, but not quite sure yet how to do that.

My B plan is just to get my Laravel app installed on a dedicated VPS(e.g. EC2) with the package and php-gd present, which I could use as a service.